# System wide dark theme

Tags: firefox, themes

I am asking this question having been looking for dark theme for Firefox. I know of no theme that fully darkens the browser especially website pages. I am now using FT DeepDark and askubuntu has a white page just as all other websites. It might make sense because these are browser themes.

So my question is there a way to have dark webpages also? And is there a quick way t switch between a light and dark theme? Preferably automatically based on day/night?

And lastly, the title says it. Is there aa system-wide (also affecting applications like vim and browsers) dark theme and the possibility to automate the switching? I also just found a similar one [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/eyeguard/http://). The plus for the Firefox one is you can edit the color and it has an automatic timer which you can control. This seems promising.

PS: I recently switched from Gnome to i3.

**Update**: I already have add-ons like [Dark Theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-theme/annfbnbieaamhaimclajlajpijgkdblo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) one for Chrome but they are GUI-specific. They do not deal with the backgrounds of websites. The  only one I use that deals with backgrounds is [Eye Guard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/night-mode-eye-guard/pcoddialcapoppmmfdcmbfoicoiggjpk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

Comment: have you tried? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/turn-off-the-lights/

Comment: This one is not available for my platform (weird). Mreover, I've used something like it before (not recently) and it seems to target video websites. I am looking for something that I don't need to switch on every time I launch a browser. (see update to my question)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility I found are two add-ons for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/eyeguard/) and [Chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/night-mode-eye-guard/pcoddialcapoppmmfdcmbfoicoiggjpk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) called Eye Guard.
The Firefox one gives you control over the color, and the time it operates.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found TT Deep Dark very effective. Alternatively, enable the compact dark theme that comes with the latest firefox version from Mozilla (or install Nightly)!

But this will only affect the browser. For system wide effect, I would enable the Global Dark Theme option in Gnome Tweak Tool, and use dark themes for both shell and GTK+. My favorite shell themes are Gnome Shell, United Arch Dark and Numix Dark. For GTK+ I use Numix.

All this is for Gnome 3.24, though. I can't say anything about Unity, because I loathe it with a burning passion and have never touched it save when it first came out.

Comment: Thanks @Sumuel. Did you mean FT (or TT?) Deep Dark? I am already using it but it doesn't affect the websites background. For Gnome I was using a dark theme also. What I was implying is whether there's a way t have a system-wide (including browsers & website backgrounds)  instead of doing all these individually. Having moved to i3 I am using a dark background. I was trying an automated way to change the wallpaper but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The TT Deep Dark theme is for the browser window only. It's part of the Firefox themes set. If you want to customize the webpage background, install the add on Stylish!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware as to how can we make the webpages dark as well but for the system wide application of the dark themes, you can install `lxappearance` and then use any theme (I personally use `Arc Dark Theme`).

For installing that theme you can follow the instructions here :

`https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme`